# Take image from S3. Rotate it and again save rotated image on the S3 server

Tags: php, image, symfony, amazon-s3

I am working on rotate image functionality.

End users has option to rotate the images. I have given ajax call to rotate the image.

I have image URL like `http://myServerName/e8520a11e5809268b920138badc416cf`

I have tried implementing below steps:

```
    $src = http://myServerName/e8520a11e5809268b920138badc416cf;
    $content = PCurl::get($src);
    $originalFile = tempnam("/tmp", "tempImageContent");   
    file_put_contents($originalFile, $content);
    $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($originalFile);  //only for jpg file. written switch statmt
    $rotate = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);
    $rotatedTmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'rotatedThumbnailImage');
    imagejpeg($rotate, $rotatedTmpFile ,100);
```

Storing it on S3.
But I am facing below error when S3 returns the hash key. And I am trying to see image using `http://bucketname/hash_key`

```
<Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

Please help!!

Comment: Do you get this response when reading from S3 or when writing to S3? This error typically happens when you don't have permissions to read from/write to a bucket/prefix. Do you own this bucket? Are you using any SDK to read from/write to S3? Are you using any AWS credentials or is the bucket public?

Comment: Thanks Viccari for reply. We have our own bucket. As I discovered, the problem is in replacing the existing image on S3. IF you have worked on replacing the s3 image then please guide me to achive this.

Comment: It's hard to help more without additional details. Where's the code that reads from S3? Where's the code that writes to S3? What are the S3 bucket permissions? Remember to not paste credentials or sensitive data here.